# Yum repository configuration on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum

I'm trying to install postgis on an Amazon EC2 instance, the instance is running Red Hat, and by following this tutorial: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation#Configure_your_YUM_repository .

I should append `exclude=postgresql*`
to `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf`,

but the file does not exist! What I have under `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d` is:

- priorities.conf
- update-motd.conf
- upgrade-helper.conf

What should I do?

Comment: What version of red hat are you on?

Comment: Have you registered a Red Hat subscription with the  RH subscription manager? Perhaps it only creates that once subscribed? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see the exclude line is designed so that it will stop postgres installation from the official repositories and instead pull it from the postgis ones.

As such just find where your repo configuration is and add the lines there.

If you are using the Amazon provided AMI (Amazon Linux) it is in fact based on fedora and not rhel.

If it is indeed rhel just install yum-rhn-plugin and you should have the file.

Answer (score 0):

The one you are looking for is a very specific file. If you can't find it, simply open the file `/etc/yum.conf` and enter the exclude line into this file.

This file is like the parent file for yum, so if you run any yum command, then this file will be consulted and actions will be taken accordingly.

Thanx

Comment: This would _globally_ exclude PostgreSQL, which isn't what he wants.

Comment: Hmmm ... might have mis-interpreted the question. My bad. Though after trying now, I am not really able to understand the question :(